# What is the legality of creating a messenger application with end-to-end encryption in Autralia?

Tags: software, privacy, australia, encryption

The `encrypted messages` will be stored in the `server`, but no one will be able to decode them except the users.
What is the `legality` of creating a messenger application with `end-to-end encryption` for countries like `AUSTRALIA` etc? it will be a global application, so there `will be customers all around the globe`.
Every application or messages should be able to read by the `government officials` when needed? if so, how `whatsapp` software exists? I just wanna `protect the privacy of my customers`. But still if it's encrypted and no one can decode, then `will it be a criminal offense for the app creator/owner`? should I provide a backdoor to the government?

Comment: Your problem is not just Australia because you want to operate globally. Thus, you need thus comply with **every** law in **every** country you operate in.

Comment: @Trish can you shed some light here to find if Australia or USA Uk allow encryption and what things or permissions should I get? I'm not asking for specific steps, I just don't have any idea where to start getting approvals etc or which keywords/technical terms to be searched in google.

Comment: Try to google with good keywords: `Australia encryption law` brings [this](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/about-us/our-portfolios/national-security/lawful-access-telecommunications/data-encryption) from the Australian Government. With the Keywort `UK encryption law` you get [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption_ban_proposal_in_the_United_Kingdom) which points to the [Investigatory Powers Act 2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Investigatory_Powers_Act_2016) which in turn was made inoperable by the ECJ ruling on it leading to the The Data Retention and Acquisition Regulations 2018...

Comment: Its just not possible to ban encryption nowadays. People just won't accept any modern communication software that does not use encryption.